# How to ask user to unlock phone

Tags: android

I have a service that shows a view on top of the Android dialer. Now, if the phone is locked, my service can theoretically still show up, but cannot be interacted with due to security constrains (or so I've read). That's fine, but I do want to prompt the user to then unlock the phone so my overlay can become active.

If I launch an activity the user will be prompted for his password/pattern, but I don't want to launch an activity - I want to stay on the phone page, but with the phone unlocked.

Comment: Could you display a notification. They show up even if phone is locked

Comment: I am displaying a notification (to unlock), but I like the security of having the user manually unlock before getting access to the overlay.

Comment: I am facing same issue! Did you find any alternatives?

Comment: No, only the one I'm using in my own answer. It works, but it's not pretty.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found an ugly solution:

1. Make dummy activity that finishes in resume.
2. Make the task affinity nothing in manifest.
3. Launch it!

I still welcome solutions that don't require launching activities!