# How to ask user to unlock device on clicking notification action in android?

Tags: java, android

I am displaying a notification from my application and this notification has an action in it, when user clicks on the action, the corresponding action class is called with the intent I set. Now, I want to perform a particular action but before that the user needs to unlock the screen if it is pin/pattern protected. I am not able to ask user to unlock device, i.e open up the unlock keypad/pattern on lock screen.

Below is the code I have,

```
    //HandleAction is a java class that extends IntentService
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, HandleAction.class);
    intent.putExtra(key, "my_value"); //Used to send information to action class
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent,
                                 PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
    //set the title, icon etc for builder and add action as below
    notification.addAction(icon, "my_label", pi);
```

When user clicks on the notification action, I get the control to onHandleIntent in MyAction.java 
In here, I want to request user to unlock device if password protected and then perform an action.
How can I request user to unlock device in onHandleIntent?

I came across using KeyguardManager and KeyguardLock to acheive this but keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock is deprecated method and I want to avoid this. So, the next was using "FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON" and "FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON" but I am unable to figure out how to use them in this context. I don't launch any window from my action class, it is just an operation like incrementing my counter. After clicking it the notification should disappear, perform my action and thats it.

I found a similar question [Unlock phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34179195/how-to-ask-user-to-unlock-phone) , but the way it was did is by launching a dummy/empty activity.

Thanks in advance for any help, suggestions :)

Comment: Were you able to get anywhere with this?

Comment: Nope! The only solution I got was the Keyguard manager and the empty activity :(

Comment: Just try to open an activity or do something and android will ask user to unlock I guess.

Answer (score 6):

In the Activity you are opening (that is behind the lock screen) you should tell system to lift the keyguard (e.g. in `onCreate()`)

For API >= 26

```
KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
km.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null); // you may add callback listener here
```

For API < 26:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

If device is not locked securely it would unlock it immediately, and if it is locked, it will ask user to do it.

Comment: This is good because I can also have a callback listening for `onDismissCancelled` and if for example I launched an Activity but the user cancelled the unlock, I can finish the Activity. I wonder how to do this though before API 26?

Answer (score 3):

Use Activity intent in pending intent insted of Service

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(key, "my_value"); //Used to send information to action class
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
                                 PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Ok that works like previous answer but also before API 26. Thank you!