# Unlock screen on click of notification in lock screen android

Tags: android

I have a custom notification shown on the lock screen. I am using a broadcast pending intent to send a message to my app once the notification is clicked. Which later starts an activity in the broadcast receiver.

The problem is, once I click on the notification, It does not ask the user to unlock the screen but the activity is launched behind the lock-screen. I can see that when I manually unlock the screen.

My requirement is to ask the user to unlock the screen as soon as the broadcast is sent by the notification's click event. How do I do that?

Here is the code I tried.

```
private void showNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.bigContentView = createCustomView(context);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(getNotificationId(), notification);
}

private PendingIntent getNotificationClickIntent() {
    Intent bcIntent = new Intent(OPEN_APP);
    bcIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEEP_LINK_URL, getDeepLinkUrl());
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context, getReqCode(), bcIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
}

private RemoteViews createCustomView(Context context) {
   RemoteViews customView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_layout);
   if (customView != null) {
        customView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.my_view, getNotificationClickIntent());
   }
   return customView;
}
```

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42131869/2102794):

Use Activity intent in pending intent instead of Service or Broadcast

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
                                 PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: You can check out the answer I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52610309/7131155

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34658292/how-to-ask-user-to-unlock-device-on-clicking-notification-action-in-android/42131869#42131869 see answer here