# Before running notification action, unlock device

Tags: xamarin.android

Notification with two buttons (actions). Which i handle in:

```
    public class NotificationActionHandler : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
}
```

Aim:the user to unlock the device before being allowed to press the buttons.
I tried something but it will allow press the button

How can i solve this? I tried this:[How to ask user to unlock device on clicking notification action in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34658292/how-to-ask-user-to-unlock-device-on-clicking-notification-action-in-android).

Comment: The answer solves the issue from what i see then what are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to understand your question properly as it is a tad bit ambiguous so, i am just going to assume that you are unable to convert the code and gonna do it for you:

For API>=26

```
KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager)GetSystemService(Context.KeyguardService);
km.RequestDismissKeyguard(this, null); // you may add callback listener here
```

For API<26

```
Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DismissKeyguard);
```

Or Use Activity intent in pending intent instead of Service in your Notification pending intent in the Notification service:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Context, typeof(YourActivity));
 intent.PutExtra(key, "my_value"); //Used to send information to action class
 PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.GetActivity(Context, 0, intent,
                                         PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
```

Comment: RequestDismissKeyguard can be called programmatically whenever user wants to show unlock ui. And it works only in API>=26.
Is there anyway to also show this unlock ui in device with API<26 programmatically?